# WebViewClient: load web pages with no header

Tags: android, header, html, webviewclient

i'm using a WebViewClient to open a site in my Android application.
When it loads the site it shows this:

[image]

I would like to "cut" the page header, i mean i would like that the page starts from a certain point. It should be loaded like this:

[image]

Do you know any way to do this? (The website i want to load in my app is not mine)

Here is my WebViewClient in my Android app code:

```
public class MyWebView extends Fragment {
    private WebView webView;

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        String url = args.getString("url");

        webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_view, container, false);

        return view;        
    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack())
            webView.goBack();
        else
            getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry for my english.

Comment: yes one way to do would be to give  `id` to your `header` in `html` and use javascript to hide that header

Comment: I used `jQuery` for solving this issue.

Comment: The website i want to load in my app is not mine.